# Audio doesnt work in Libre office

Tags: sound, libreoffice, codecs, presentation

I want to make a powerpoint in Libreoffice(5.0.5.2) with mp3 files integrated inside. When I add mp3 files in slides, there is no audio output.I can play mp3 files separately with vlc and other players without any problem.

I am using Lubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow slides autoplay:

From menubar Go to **Slideshow - Slideshow Settings** and tick on **Auto** Mode.

[image]

Comment: I change the setting as you said but there is no audio yet.